# Simple way to find out the colour and other styling properties of an element on the web page

Tags: css

Would you be aware of any tools(preferably free) or browser plugins that would allow me to easily determine the styling properties of an element on the web page.

For example it could be a tool that would import all the styling information from the css files associated with the page and presented it as an in-line styling.

Eventually some sort of  browser plugin that would alow me to select an element and then would dispaly the styling information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari and Chrome have a built in Web Inspector, right click and select Inspect Element. Firefox has the Firebug plugin. IE has IE Dev Toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) will do that, at least in  Firefox.

Comment: Firebug is absolutely indispensable to my web development work. It's damned useful for casual use too, like whenever you'd like to investigate or manipulate the DOM of the page that you're looking at.

Comment: +1 Thanks, firebug does the job nicely. I accepted the Mahrdad answer as he provided the options for other browsers as well

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is the "Web Developer Toolbar" extension for FireFix.  With this extension you can enable the "Show CSS Information", clicking on an element opens a window with all appliciable CSS styles.

You can also view all CSS and do many other very helpful things with it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [web development helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper) by Nikhil Kothari for IE

And [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the colour you are after in Firefox, you can use [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/), which lets you eyedrop any colour off the viewport (including the chrome!)

Answer (score 0):

for web development (overall graphics) the plugin [WebDeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/60) for firefox.
Light and powerfull